# Share the same test over test classes in xUnit

Tags: .net, unit-testing, .net-core, xunit, xunit.net

I am just curious if it is possible to share tests between classes in xUnit.
Lets say we have the following:

An interface `IConfigurationProvider` and

`ConfigurationProvider`

`CachedConfigurationProvider`

are implementing this interace.

I have a few more but lets keep it simple.

My xUnit tests:

`ConfigurationProvider`:

just testing if the provider is saving the config correctly to the database

`CachedConfigurationProvider`:

testing if the provider is saving the config correctly to the database **AND** if caching is correct

As you can see the `ConfigurationProvider` and the `CachedConfigurationProvider` include exactly the same unit test. It would be great to just write the test once and tell the test classes "do this test with this"

I tried to write a test class `GlobalUnitTests` with a test with the attributes `[Theory]` and `[InlineData()]`. I thought I just can put the different providers in the `[InlineData()]` attribute but unfortunately that didn't work. Now I am clueless but I don't want to write the same test ten times and change it ten times when I have to make a change.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39570641/xunit-theory-test-using-generics) help?