# How to use NUnit TestCases with Generics with where constraint?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, generics, nunit, testcase

I am trying to use NUnit with a Generic TestCase as per this answer:
[NUnit TestCase with Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43339950/15488899) from [@György Kőszeg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5114784/gy%c3%b6rgy-k%c5%91szeg).

However, due to what I test, I need to use a [`where` constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint) with a complex type passed in (class), otherwise [the compiler erros with error CS0314](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0314?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0314)).

```cs
[TestCase(typeof(SomeClass))]
[TestCase(typeof(SomeOtherClass))]
public void GenericTest<T>(T instance) where T : ISomeInterface
{
    Console.WriteLine(instance);
}
```

`SomeClass` and `SomeOtherClass` are valid classes that implement `ISomeInterface`.

This does fail with the following error:

> An exception was thrown while loading the test.
> System.ArgumentException: GenericArguments[0], 'System.RuntimeType', on '[...]GenericTestT' violates the constraint of type 'ISomeInterface'.

I can't get that to work. If I change it to `nameof(SomeClass)` to try it with the string value, I get the same error that `String` does not match the constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh dear, of course it has to interfere it from the type.

As such, it get's a little harder as `TestCases` need to be static, but we can use [`TestCaseSource`](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/testcasesource.html).

```cs
[TestCaseSource(nameof(GetTestCases))]
public void GenericTest<T>(T instance) where T : ISomeInterface
{
    Console.WriteLine(instance);
}

private static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> GetTestCases()
{
    yield return new TestCaseData(new SomeClass());
    yield return new TestCaseData(new SomeOtherClass());
}
```

---

As an unrelated addition, you can [discard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards) the `instance` if you don't actually use it and just wanted to use it for the type:

```cs
[TestCaseSource(nameof(GetTestCases))]
public void GenericTest<T>(T _) where T : ISomeInterface
{
    // ...
}
```